# NTLM and InitializeSecureContext - what are the right flags for fContextReq?

Tags: ntlm, http-authentication

When performing NTLM authentication sequence in HTTP communications, Windows API function called InitializeSecureContext is used. It includes fContextReq parameter, which accepts the set of flags that regulate the exact behavior of the library in regards to handling challenges and creating responses.

For years we've been using  ISC_REQ_INTEGRITY | с ISC_REQ_CONNECTION, and this worked fine for most servers. Now with McAfee Web proxy this combination of flags produces the INVALID_TOKEN error in InitializeSecurityContext on the second step. Removing ISC_REQ_INTEGRITY flag helps with McAfee server (not tested with ISA yet).

The question is whether the flag was used incorrectly (and McAfee proxy is correct by not using it on its side) OR this is a glitch of McAfee proxy OR the set of flags are to be prearranged between parties by design? I understand that in different scenarios there are different flags to be used, and my question is specifically about NTLM in HTTP authentication, where the other party and its capabilities and used flags are not known beforehand.